# Como ocultar o bloquear un input desde un combobox en asp.net mvc?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html5, asp.net, bootstrap

quisiera poder ocultar o bloquear 2 input despues de los 2 primero items en combobox, todo esta hecho en MVC y EF, asp.net

tengo este combo:

[image: Tengo este combo]

```
<div class="form-row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-auto my-1">
               <label class="mr-sm-2" for="txtTipPre">Tipo de Predio:</label>
                         <select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" id="txtTipPre">
                                            <option>Agricola</option>
                                            <option>Informatica/Computacion</option>
                                             <option>Finanzas</option>  
                                             <option>Educacion</option>    
                                    </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Tengo dos Input
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
                      <div class="col">
                                <label for="txtSupAg">Habilitadas:</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="number" id="txtSupAg" />

                            </div>


                            <div class="col">
                                <label for="txtSupGan">Habilitadas:</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="number" id="txtSupGan" />

                            </div>
```

Como hago para que esos campos inputs se bloqueen o se oculten cuando se seleccione a partir del 3er item "Finanzas" y sea visible para los dos primeros de arriba?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías hacerlo con javascript ejecutando el evento onchange cuando el usuario cambie la opción seleccionada. Envías a la función el índice y verificas la selección para ocultar los inputs o mostrarlos.

```
<select onchange="hidden(this.selectedIndex)">
  ...
</select>


<script>
  function hidden(val) {
    if (val >= 2) {
      $('#txtSupAg').hide();
      $('#txtSupGan').hide();
    } else {
      $('#txtSupAg').show();
      $('#txtSupGan').show();
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, eso me ayudo bastante justamento buscaba en JS